# Does returning values from functions affect performance in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking

Let's take a look at this class and method:

```
class Test {
    protected $storage;

    public function rng() {
        $random = random_bytes(100);

        $this->storage = $random;
    }
}
```

Some random bytes are being calculated using PHP7's random_bytes() function, and the result isn't returned; it's only being stored in a property.

Let's take a look at a slightly different version of the above method:

```
class Test {
    protected $storage;

    public function rng() {
        $random = random_bytes(100);

        $this->storage = $random;

        return $random;
    }
}
```

This time, the result is returned. I am wondering if there's any performance hit when a value is being returned.

Comment: If you need access to that value from outside the class, then you're going to have a performance overhead in accessing it, whether that's direct access, a getter method, or returning it from the rng method - take a look at the VLD  opcode for the two options [#1](https://3v4l.org/kSuUf/vld#tabs) and [#2](https://3v4l.org/Q3uue/vld#tabs) and you will see an additional operation... the time that it takes is measured in nanoseconds, but there is a performance difference

Comment: Whether you return values from a method or not shouldn't be assessed by any performance overhead, but by the actual requirements of that method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test script #1: **not returning value**

```
<?php

class Test {
    protected $storage;

    public function rng() {
        $random = random_bytes(100);

        $this->storage = $random;
    }
}

$instance = new Test;

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $instance->rng();
}

$end = microtime(true);

$diff = $end - $start;

printf('Not returning: %.25f', $diff);

print PHP_EOL;
```

Test script #2: **returning value**

```
<?php

class Test {
    protected $storage;

    public function rng() {
        $random = random_bytes(100);

        $this->storage = $random;

        return $random;
    }
}

$instance = new Test;

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $instance->rng();
}

$end = microtime(true);

$diff = $end - $start;

printf('Returning: %.25f', $diff);

print PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

```
$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Not returning: 0.0937850475311279296875000

$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Not returning: 0.0939409732818603515625000

$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Not returning: 0.0953028202056884765625000

$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Returning: 0.0947949886322021484375000

$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Returning: 0.0930099487304687500000000

$ php -f functions-returning-values-benchmark.php
Returning: 0.0935621261596679687500000
```

### Conclusion

There is no performance hit.

Tested on AWS Debian Jessie t2.micro instance (1vCore, 1 GiB RAM) running PHP 7.0.7.

Comment: How expensive is generating 100 random bytes?  Doesn't that probably completely dominate returning a value or not?

Comment: @PeterCordes Extremely cheap, but `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is even cheaper. Whether it dominates returing a value or not, I don't know, but I'd guess so, yea.

Comment: I'd guess that something like a simple scalar integer `a += 2` would be about the same kind of cost as returning a value, if returning costs anything in the interpreter when the caller doesn't use the result.